# Objective C: Accessing constants from other classes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, class, constants

I have a constant in one class that I want to access from another.
I want to access these:

```
#define kStateRunning 1
#define kStateGameOver 2
#define kStateMenu 3
```

which are in my `GameController.h` from `Level1.m`. In `Level1.h` I have `@class GameController` as well as an import in the implementation file.

I tried searching for an answer, but I'm not sure if I'm wording all this correctly.

Comment: If the constants are in gamecontroller.h, and you're importing that in level1.m, they should be available. Are you asking if you're doing it right, or is is not working?

Comment: Something is missing.  If the constants are defined in `GameController.h` then to access them why not just `#import GameController.h`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `#define myConstant`, `myConstant` will be known since you import your file. Define them at the beginning of your `GameController.h` between the import and the `@Interface` for example.

Then if you import `GameController.h` in one of your other files (let's take `Level1.m` for example). You can use it, without prefixing it. Just use `myConstant`

Comment: I've been trying to prefix it, that was my problem

Comment: if you use #define, it's not a part of the class. You can have a file with all your defined constants for example, and no class in that file.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use `#define` as you lose any checking from the compiler. Generally you use a constant to avoid using magic values throughout your code that can be spelt wrong or typed wrong.

In the Apple docs for [Coding Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html) they tell you how you should approach each type of constant.

For simple integers like you have, they suggest `enums` are the best option. They are used extensively in the Apple frameworks so you know they are good.

You would still need to define it in your header.

e.g. (Use your own prefix instead of `PS`)

```
typedef enum {
    PSGameStateRunning  = 1,
    PSGameStateGameOver,
    PSGameStateMenu,
} PSGameState;
```

This also has the advantage of being a type that you can pass into/return from functions if you require